# Add or trigger event after inner content to page

Tags: events, triggers, dojo

I have links on a table to edit or delete elements, that elements can be filtered. I filtered and get the result using ajax and get functions. After that I added (display) the result on the table using `inner.html`, the issue here is that after filtering the links on the elements not work, cause a have the dojo function like this

```
dojo.ready(function(){

    dojo.query(".delete-link").onclick(function(el){
    var rowToDelete = dojo.attr(this,"name");
    if(confirm("Really delete?")){
.......
}

});
```

I need to trigger the event after filtering, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that you're using Dojo <= 1.5 here.)

The quick answer is that you need to extract the code in your `dojo.ready` into a separate function, and call that function at the end of your Ajax call's `load()` callback. For example, make a function like this:

```js
var attachDeleteEvents = function() 
    dojo.query(".delete-link").onclick(function(el){
        var rowToDelete = dojo.attr(this,"name");
        if(confirm("Really delete?")){
            .......
        }
    });
};
```

Then you call this function both in `dojo.ready` and when your Ajax call completes:

```js
dojo.ready(function() { attachDeleteEvents(); });
....
var filter = function(someFilter) {
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "some/url.html?filter=someFilter",
        handleAs: "text",
        load: function(newRows) {
            getTableBody().innerHTML = newRows;
            attachDeleteEvents();
        }
    });
};
```

That was the quick answer. Another thing that you may want to look into is **event delegation**. What happens in the code above is that every row gets an onclick event handler. You could just as well have a single event handler on the table itself. That would mean there would be no need to reattach event handlers to the new rows when you filter the table.

In recent versions of Dojo, you could get some help from `dojo/on` - something along the lines of:

```js
require(["dojo/on"], function(on) {
    on(document.getElementById("theTableBody"), "a:click", function(evt) {...});
```

This would be a single event handler on the whole table body, but your event listener would only be called for clicks on the `<a>` element.

Because (I'm assuming) you're using 1.5 or below, you'll have to do it a bit differently. We'll still only get one event listener for the whole table body, but we have to make sure we only act on clicks on the `<a>` (or a child element) ourselves.

```js
dojo.connect(tableBody, "click", function(evt) {

    var a = null, name = null;
    // Bubble up the DOM to find the actual link element (which
    // has the data attribute), because the evt.target may be a 
    // child element (e.g. the span). We also guard against 
    // bubbling beyond the table body itself.
    for(a = evt.target; 
        a != tableBody && a.nodeName !== "A"; 
        a = a.parentNode);

    name = dojo.attr(a, "data-yourapp-name");
    if(name && confirm("Really delete " + name + "?")) {
        alert("Will delete " + name);
    }
});
```

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qCZhs/1/

Comment: I tried it but did not work, I'm using 1.6 version, after the filtered I got null in this variable var rowToDelete = dojo.attr(this,"name"); and I'm using POST